Trying to open a csv file in juypter notebook with pandas, keep recieving syntax error not sure what im doing wrong
Not sure what the problem is, the file is there, and it is spelled correctly. I can't seem to get python pandas to read this csv file so I can start working with it.
NOTE: Trying to work through the virtual internship for JPMorgan Chase on theForage.com. Just learning Python with Jupyter Notebooks.
import pandas as pd
path = ("C:\Users\stone\Downloads\transactions.csv")
df = pd.read_csv(path)

  File "<ipython-input-10-798725d5a1b8>", line 2
    path = ("C:\Users\stone\Downloads\transactions.csv")
           ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape


Is your code actually formatted as it appears above? If so, you're probably going to have syntax issues.
